# custom javascript cannot return client ID var google tag manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have tried to get the client ID with custom javascript but it cannot return the value. Below is the code is tried. Would like to seek help from all experts. Thanks.

```
    function () {
  return function () {
    try {
      var trackers = ga.getAll();
      trackers.forEach(function(tracker) {
        var cid = tracker.get('clientId');
        tracker.set('dimension1', cid);
      });
    } catch (e) {}
  }
}
```

[It cannot return a normal client ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TF2dg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your custom variable returns a function, not a value (since the function is never actually executed).

A better way to get the clientId for each current tracker is to use a custom task in Google Analytics ([tasks](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/tasks) are basically individual steps in the tracker lifecycle, from checking if a client id exists to assemble the payload to actually sending the data). A task is a Javascript function that is added to the GA tag via the "set fields" configuration. Tasks have access to the tracker data model and can add, remove or modify values from the payload.

The only task you can use via GTM is the customTask, which as the name suggests, adds custom capabilities to the tracker.

If you create a custom javascript variable called e.g. "getClientId" with the following code:

```
function() {
  // Modify customDimensionIndex to match the index number you want to send the data to
  var customDimensionIndex = 5;
  return function(model) {
    model.set('dimension' + customDimensionIndex, model.get('clientId'));
  }
}
```

then go to your GA settings tag, and in the "set field" configuration set the field name "customTask" with the variable as value, the clientId will be extracted from the data model and added to the payload as custom dimension.

Better than my explanation is [Simo Ahavas GTM tip for setting the client id via custom tasks.](https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/use-customtask-access-tracker-values-google-tag-manager/)

Comment: First of all, thanks for the reply. I have added the variable, trigger and tag already. And I have set the field name customTask also. I have set the custom dimension in the GA. But it seems that the tag cannot be fired successfully. It is still returning function but no value in the field.